# Склонение Кривой Рог

Tags: склонение

А вот интересует вопрос по поводу склонения Кривой Рог. Если в предложении говорится - "В этом году в Кривом Роге пройдет грандиозное мероприятие". Тоже нужно писать Кривой Рог?

Answer (score 1):

Уточните вопрос.

Ваше предложение написано совершенно правильно: *"В этом году в Кривом Роге пройдет грандиозное мероприятие".* Никаких правок ни в "склонении", ни где еще не требуется.

Что вы подразумеваете под "писать Кривой Рог"? Если это предложение заменить падеж в исходной фразе, то конечно нет. Все топонимы и названия изменяются по падежам (кроме некоторых заведомо несколнямых неславянских).

Даже если заменить на "городе Кривой Рог" то все равно требуется согласование в падеже: 
*"В этом году в городе Кривом Роге пройдет грандиозное мероприятие".* И никаких "тоже".

//---------

С подачи Сержа обнаружил у Розенталя подходящее правило.
Но пока не могу взять за истину, поскольку очень странно, что столь важный и значимый случай нигде кроме как у Розенталя не оговорен.

> > 2. Не согласуются вышеприведенные названия, если они выражены:
> >        1)      словосочетанием – в городе Кривой Рог, из села Чистый Ключ;

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm
(§197. Приложения – географические названия)

Пока привожу просто для сведения, следовать этому правилу считаю преждевременным.

//------- (11.05.2015)

Увидел старый ответ. Уже согласен. Вернее сказать, до меня дошел смысл.
Конечно же "в городе Кривой Рог". Я раньше погорячился.

Comment: Нет, "в городе Кривой Рог". Топонимы, выраженные словосочетанием, не согласуются с родовым словом.

Comment: Niemand, Это по какой грамматике? O_o?
Вы не путаете с личными именами? Типа "поселок Лев Толстой"?  Вот егго склонять действительно как-то "не есть гут". А причин для "несклонения" Кривого рога я не вижу...  
Впрочем, не могу считать себя специалистом... Попробую уточнить...

(+)
Niemand, очень нужна ссылка на источник. Ничего похожего навскидку не нашел. Есть только упоминание о "несклонении" названий типа *в городе Великие Луки*, но это случай множественного числа, он и без того очевидный.

Comment: Основная информативная функция слова "город" в таком сочетании (не считая отн. редких случаев совпадения его названия с названием, напр. реки) - возобновление произношения и написания сравнительно малознакомого названия, а для этого нужен именительный падеж (слово "город" создаёт условия для его применения). К примеру, все ли видели в написанном виде название города Вышний Волочёк? Кто не видел или не запомнил, тот по склоняемой форме, скорее всего, в следующий раз напишет окончание через "о". То же с "городом Колпино": падеж названия исключает ошибочное восприятие как "город Колпин".

Comment: @behemothus, а почему вы не доверяете правилу у Розенталя. Хотя и я не нашел(кроме Розенталя),подобного правила. Тем не менее не вижу оснований не доверять правилу.

Comment: Серж, я же сказал. Такое актуальное правило, будь оно общепризнанным, не могло не быть продублировано массой источников. 
Это не значит, что я не доверяю Розенталю вообще, но у него, как почти у любого автора,  - особенно в изданиях, доработанных уже после его смерти - есть предостаточно мест, нуждающихся в проверке и осмыслении.
  
Если угодно, я хотел бы получить комментарий от автора, более авторитетного, чем я.

Comment: В данном случае меня смущает прежде всего нелогичность подобного изъятия из общего правила. То, что там Alex_ander написал (насчет условий восприятия исходной формы) малоубедительно само по себе, но уж к составным названиям относится менее всего.  Разве кого-то модет поставить в затруднительное положение форма "В [городе] Кривом Роге" или "В [городе] Вышнем Волочке"?! Наоборот, двойное согласование снимает всякие вопросы об исходной форме. Не "Кривое же Рого"? И не "Вышнее Волочко".

Comment: Я спрошу у Грамоты. У них на портале в правилах о склонении географических названий этот пункт не упоминается.

Comment: О! Давайте. Мне они уже пригрозили вечным баном, вряд ли был бы толк от вопроса.

Comment: В понедельник спрошу.

Answer (score 0):

Местные жители Кривого Рога, называют город в обыходе "Кривбас".

Comment: так это вроде не город, а сам бассейн. И почему с одним "С"? По-украински?

Answer (score 0):

Ниманд совершенно прав: названия выраженные словосочетанием не склоняются с родовым термином( хотя склоняемость таких наименований сейчас  становится допустимой). 
См.ответ справочной службы "Грамма.ру". 
опрос 2024:    Как правильно: ельнинцы или ельчане? Думаю, первое. Житель города Елец или житель города Ельца?

Ответ:   Конечно же, ельчанами (ельчанин и ельчанка) следует называть именно жителей Ельца, а жителей Ельни - ельнинцами либо ельНИчанами. Что же касается вопроса о том, как правильно - "житель города Елец" или "житель города Ельца", то, хотя названия городов, выраженные склоняемым существительным, в норме должны согласовываться с определяемым словом (в городе Саратове), ***многими исследователями отмечается, что тенденция к неизменяемости географических названий, возникшая еще в прошлом веке и первоначально распространявшаяся лишь на такие названия, которые выражены словосочетанием (в городе Кривой Рог***), формой множественного числа (из города Черкассы), именами собственными, чей род не совпадает с основным понятием (в городе Ровно, в селе Углянец), и именами собственными на -ово(ёво), - ыно(ино) (в городе Иваново, из поселка Пушкино), постепенно все больше осваивается речью, распространяется на все большее число топонимов и ныне рассматривается как допустимый вариант.

Comment: Серж, простите, но информация о том, что "***некоторыми исследователями*** отмечается тенденция... и ***рассматривается как допустимый вариант*** даже на грамме опубликованная, говорит только о том, что правила такого они не знают.   

Другое дело, что текст, судя по всему механически позаимстывован у Розенталя...
  
>>2.      Не согласуются вышеприведенные названия, если они выражены:  
>1)      словосочетанием – в городе Кривой Рог, из села Чистый Ключ;  
   
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm  
(§197. Приложения – географические названия)

Comment: Вот это действительно забавно.
Странно, что никто более пока этого правила не отмечал. 
Так что при всем уважении к Розенталю пока не могу принять за истину.